# Delay when pressing backspace on only one keyboard model

Tags: usb, keyboard

I am saddled with two MaxKeyboard Nighthawk X8 keyboards (USB mechanical). I can type with them fine, but I've found that, in Ubuntu (both 18.04 and 20.04, it seems), there is a delay whenever I switch from backspacing to typing, and vice/versa.

That is, If I type [a] [backspace] [b], there will be about a one second before the "a" disappears, and then another before the "b" apppears. If I do [a]x10 [backspace]x10 [b]x10, there are still only two delays--before the "aaaaaaaaaa" start to disappear and before the "bbbbbbbbbb" start to appear.

Most importantly, there is no such delay when using a Lenovo KBRFBD71 "Professional Wirless Keyboard" (slim-profile keyboard with proprietary USB dongle) on linux, or either keyboard on Windows. So, it's something about the specific communication between this Nighthawk X8 and Linux.

All the options in "Typing Assist (AccessX)" (including "Slow Keys") are off. How can I go about debugging this? Is there some way to tell Linux to treat this keyboard differently, so this doesn't happen?